Using Rolle theorem to find solutions of equations.
I want to show that between two solutions of the equation $(1) : \;\sin(x)e^x=1$ there exist a solution to the equation $(2) :\; \cos(x)e^x=-1$. So let $x_1$ and $x_2$ be two solutions of $(1)$ and let $f(x)=\sin(x)e^x-1$ then $f(x_1)=f(x_2)=0$ and $f$ continuous on $[x_1,x_2]$ and differentiable on $(x_1,x_2)$ so by Rolle theorem there exists $c\in (x_1,x_2)$ such that $f'(c)=0$ this gives that $sin(c)=-cos(c)$ but i don't see how to continue.

It is not clear to me whether you are required to apply Rolle's theorem or you thought it could be helpful

Start with $f(x) = e^{-x}-\sin x$

thanks @HariShankar, it works!

@HariShankar excellent idea
